# rsync changed files to different directory

Tags: linux, rsync

What I am trying to do it to rsync from remote to local and also put all changed files to a different directory.

For example, in remote box,

```
/tmp
 -file1.txt
 -file2.txt
 -file3.txt
```

in my local

```
/tmp
 -file1.txt
 -file2.txt

/new
```

If I do a rsync, my local will be

```
/tmp
 -file1.txt
 -file2.txt
 -file3.txt

/new
 -file3.txt
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be interesting to see if you ever get an answer to this, but I think that rsync doesn't have this capability. If I had to solve this problem, I'd embed the rsync call inside a script which did a before-and-after comparison of /tmp and noted any new or changed files.

Comment: post what command you type that results this way !

Answer (score 3):

Try the option `--compare-dest=DIR`, for example:

```
rsync --compare-dest=/tmp remotebox:/tmp /new
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a bit of tinkering to get it to work correctly for me, but basically I had to use rsync twice. This seems horribly wrong to me, but as long as it works for me it does not matter. The first call uses `--compare-dest` to only sync new files to the `/new` folder. The second call syncs the `/tmp` folder as normal.

It should look something like this:

```
rsync --compare-dest=/tmp remotebox:/tmp /new
rsync remotebox:/tmp /tmp
```